double http request when IP changes
I have strange situation which I can observe, very rarely, on production.
I have login page, where user enters pin, and after sixth digit screen and keyboard are disabled.
From backend perspective I can see that login request has been called twice in the same time.
What's important in each of strange cases we noticed that IP has been changed.
We have 3 million users, and only 5 times in last month this situation occurs. Everytime with changing IP.
My questions is why and on which layer request is multiplied? How can I protect my app against that behavior?
Also, how can I repeat this situation on my test device?
I'm using retrofit 2.9 and okhttp 4.10.

Likely related to https://medium.com/inloopx/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace
OkHttp will retry requests it considers safe retry, generally a GET, specific IOException or if it knows the request wasn't actually fully sent.
